# Buildbot multiple slaves working on same directory efficiently

Tags: python, buildbot

I am using "buildbot" to accommodate some git projects, however I cannot seem to write it in an efficient manner. Lets say I have a project named "Project" and have 3 different componenets within them namely "A", "B", "C" and have three different builders for them namely "Builder_A", "Builder_B", "Builder_C". Currently the scripts for the builders are almost same, except they are building different components within them. Here is my sample build routine for each builder.

```
make clean
git checkout
make 
run sample tests
```

The problem occurs at git checkout, each bot is doing this step separately. However, if only one did this step it would be better in performance. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that the `git checkout` step itself is taking too long? If so, how long? And are you really issuing a `git checkout` step through a shell script instead of using the [`Git`](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#buildbot.steps.source.buildbot.steps.source.git.Git) step? If so, why?

Comment: Git checkout is done with Git step. If only one builder is active, the checkout takes about 10mins with clobber enabled. With all builders it is 3times the normal checkout time. We would like to continue to use clobber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I read you suggesting is that one builder should checkout your source and then the other builders would depend on this first builder to get their source rather than perform their own checkout. I would advise against this. In effect this makes builders dependent on the files that are present in the working directory of another builder. It *is possible* to write a configuration that will do this but it will complicate your configuration quite a bit.

There are other things you can do:

1. Use the `shallow` option so that git does not fetch the whole history of a project. This would enable you to continue using `clobber` (as you mentioned in a comment).
2. Use an option other than `clobber`. `fresh`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I will go with clobber on main builder and fresh for the smaller builders. However, I would like to test how will one builder checking while the other builders starve till the first builder finishes with the checking out.

Comment: Glad to help, but I don't understand what you mean in your comment. (The 2nd sentence, specifically.) If this is a brand new question, then you should post it formally as a question rather than as a comment.

Comment: It is currently a thought, but if number of builders increases I guess I have to test that.